# Calling other sub using parameter throwing syntax error

Tags: excel, vba

While calling other sub with two parameter, i am getting syntax error.

UpdatingActiveWorkbook(workBookPath,13) - highlighting as syntax error.

```
Sub UpdatingActiveWorkbook(workBookPath As String, workbookname As Integer)


Workbooks.Open workBookPath

Workbooks("MacroWorkbook.xlsm").Activate
Workbooks(workbookname).Activate


ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub

Sub callingOtherModule()


UpdatingActiveWorkbook("C:\334804_PF_Calculation6.xls",13)



End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

either you:

1) use the (obsolete) `Call` keyword

and then you can keep parentheses:

```
    Call UpdatingActiveWorkbook("C:\334804_PF_Calculation6.xls", 13)
```

2) or remove parentheses:

```
    UpdatingActiveWorkbook "C:\334804_PF_Calculation6.xls", 13
```